# In JavaScript / jQuery what is the best way to convert a number with a comma into an integer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-parsing

I want to convert the string "15,678" into a value 15678. Methods `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` are both returning 15 for "15,678." Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The simplest option is to remove all commas: `parseInt(str.replace(/,/g, ''), 10)`

Answer (score 11):

One way is to remove all the commas with:

```
strnum = strnum.replace(/\,/g, '');
```

and *then* pass that to parseInt:

```
var num = parseInt(strnum.replace(/\,/g, ''), 10);
```

But you need to be careful here. The use of commas as thousands separators is a cultural thing. In some areas, the number `1,234,567.89` would be written `1.234.567,89`.

Comment: `parseInt()` should be provided a radix when being called, to eliminate the hex interpretation of a number.

Answer (score 8):

If you only have numbers and commas:

```
+str.replace(',', '')
```

The `+` casts the string `str` into a number if it can. To make this as clear as possible, wrap it with parens:

```
(+str.replace(',', ''))
```

therefore, if you use it in a statement it is more separate visually (+ +x looks very similar to ++x):

```
var num = (+str1.replace(',', '')) + (+str1.replace(',', ''));
```

Javascript code conventions (See "Confusing Pluses and Minuses", second section from the bottom):

http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: your solution will replace only the first comma, not all of them so it will not work for numbers >= 1,000,000

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
var value = parseInt("15,678".replace(",", ""));
```

Comment: your solution will replace only the first comma, not all of them so it will not work for numbers >= 1,000,000

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek the question was "I want to convert the string "15,678" into a value 15678". My answer solves this problem. I'm being pedantic here, of course, but technically correct ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex to remove the commas before parsing, like this

```
parseInt(str.replace(/,/g,''), 10)
//or for decimals as well:
parseFloat(str.replace(/,/g,''))
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/B4R8C/).