# Converting HTML5 data type to number

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

Background: I would like to add and subtract numbers. I'm using HTML data-attributes. parseInt() and Number() aren't working as I thought they would be.

```
   <div class="originalNumber" data-original-number="1,000,000">1,000,000</div>

   <div class="bucket1" data-bucket="100,000">100,000</div>
   <div class="bucket2" data-bucket="200,000">200,000</div>
   <div class="bucket3" data-bucket="300,000">300,000</div>
```

I get the original number:

```
   var getOriginal=$(".originalNumber").data("original-number");
```

console.log = 1,000,000

Now I would like to add and subtract from it. For example click bucket1 and 1,000,000 becomes 900,000 (1,000,000-100,000)

**The problem is that I cannot turn the string into a number. I've tried using parseInt() and Number() to no avail.**

```
   var getOriginal=parseInt(getOriginal);
   console.log(getOriginal);
```

returns 1

```
    var getOriginal=Number(getOriginal);
    console.log(getOriginal);
```

returns NaN

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a regex:

```
 var getOriginalNumeric = parseInt(getOriginal.replace(/[^\d\.]/gi, ''));
```

This will strip out anything but digits and decimals.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to remove all the commas from the string containing the number before using parseInt().

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083372/in-javascript-jquery-what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-with-a-comma-into) has some information on the best ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a comma is interpreted as the decimal sign, this is standard for most countries, but the US (for example) uses periods as the decimal separator.

You'd need to replace the comma's:

```
getOriginal = parseInt(getOriginal.replace(/,/g, ""), 10);
```

Here's a live example: http://codepen.io/TheDutchCoder/pen/WbbzJL