# Convert string to number in money format JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I have the string "722,311.75" and I want to convert it in number 722,311.75 (money format). The following code doesn't work.

```js
var str = "722,311.75";
var nr = parseFloat(str, 10).toFixed(2);
console.log(nr); // Returns 722.00
```

Any Idea of how I could do this?

Comment: just use `parseFloat(str.replace(/[,]/g, ""));`

Comment: "722,311.75" is not a valid number representation. `parseFloat` will only see the first number (722) and ignore anything after and inculding the comma. Also, thre is no such thing as a "money format" number in JavaScript. The number will be 722311.75, and then you can provide a modified toString function that inserts commas.

Comment: Other duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083372/in-javascript-jquery-what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-with-a-comma-int, and several others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `,` from the string before passing the string to the `parseFloat`

If the string contains more than one `,`, you can use ragex to remove all occurrences of the `,`.

The regex `/,/` will match the `,` literal from the string and `g` the global flag will make the regex to match all possible strings i.e. all the `,` from string.

```js
var str = "1,722,311.75";
var nr = parseFloat(str.replace(/,/g, ''), 10).toFixed(2);
document.write(nr);
```

---

If the string contains only one `,`, you can use `replace` with string to remove `,` from the string.

```js
var str = "722,311.75";
var nr = parseFloat(str.replace(',', ''), 10).toFixed(2);
document.write(nr);
```

**Note**: `replace(',', '')` will remove only first occurrence of `,`. See first code snippet for regex approach that will replace all the occurrences.

Comment: edit your first example. it is not valid. there will be issue if `str = "5,722,311.75";`

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev Right, that's why I've added second option with title `If the string contains more than one ,`

Comment: @Magus Thanks for helping improving the answer, but your edit overwrite my changes so have to rollback

Comment: I added comment. ok, just suggest dynamic way (without any condition).

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev If OP is sure that there will be only one `,` in string, using string with replace is faster than regex, so added that, if not then only use regex

Comment: It is common question(`Convert string to number in money format JavaScript`). `722,311.75` is just example. it may be another price.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91175/discussion-between-tushar-and-sherali-turdiyev).