# Format string '1,200' to integer 1200, with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem convert string `1,200` to integer `1200`

i need convert `1,200` to 1200 integer

how to solve my problem using javascript ?

Comment: this solution might solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255843/is-there-a-way-to-reverse-the-formatting-by-intl-numberformat-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In JavaScript / jQuery what is the best way to convert a number with a comma into an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083372/in-javascript-jquery-what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-with-a-comma-int)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To work in node and browser, use replace with regex.

```
const num = "1,200"
const parsed = Number(num.replace(/,/g, ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split on the comma, rejoin and parse into a number,
or remove the commas with a regex and parse into a number

Note that both of these methods allow for more than 1 ',' eg if 1,000, 000 - that's what the `g` is for in the regex.

```js
const str = '1,200'

const option1 = parseInt(str.split(',').join(''), 10);
const option2 = parseInt(str.replace(/,/g,''), 10);

console.log('option1 - split and join - then parse: ' + option1);
console.log('option2 - replace with regex - then parse: ' + option2);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can first replace all commas (with [`String.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)), then parse:

```js
const str = "1,200"
const parsed = +str.replaceAll(',', '')

console.log(parsed)
```

Comment: [String.prototype.replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)